# Vitest mock doesn't mock modules

Tags: jestjs, mocking, lodash, vite

I have this simple example where I want to modules in test cases but vi doesn't mock and returns the original function. I'm using vite  "vite": "^3.2.0", "vitest": "^0.25.3"

```
 import { map } from "lodash";

 vi.mock("lodash");

 describe("Inventory", () => {
     it("should",  () => {
       console.log(map);
    });
 });
```